# Библиотека для парсинга json в несколько шагов

Tags: c++, json, c++11

Задача распарсить json, приходящий по соккету. При этом нет возможности считать весь json в память, нужно парсить по частям.
Код обработки примерно представляю таким:

```
char buffer[1024];
JsonParser parser;

do
{
    int length = socket.read(buffer, 1024); // возвращает длину прочитанного
    parser.parse(buffer, length);
} while (length == 1024);

JsonObject result = parser.getResult();
```

Т.е. необходима библиотека, которой можно на вход скармливать короткие массивы, а потом в конце получить результат парсинга. Какой библиотекой можно воспользоваться для данной задачи, чтобы не изобретать велосипед?

Comment: std::stringstream и результат уже парсить. 1. https://github.com/nlohmann/json#tofrom-strings 2. https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson#usage-at-a-glance 1я медленней но удобнее 2й

Comment: Разобранное дерево объекта JSON  займет не меньше памяти, чем исходная строка. Поэтому требование "разбирать по частям" кажется странным. Возможно, тебе не нужно строить дерево объекта, а нужно обрабатывать узлы по мере поступления? Тогда см.  http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_sax.html

Comment: Запрос в гугле *c++ stream json parser* выдал [это](https://github.com/nlohmann/json). Я бы пробовал наследовать [`std::streambuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/?kw=streambuf), чтобы он работал с сетью, и скармливать его этой библиотеке.

Answer (score -1):

Сначала вычитываем json до конца и ложим его в [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) (в любом случае, до конца вычитаем и в памяти надо будет весь текст хранить):

```cpp
char buffer[1024];
std::stringstream ss;
do
{
    int length = socket.read(buffer, 1024);
    ss << buffer;
} while (length == 1024);
```

А потом используем в одну из библиотек, либо [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#tofrom-strings) либо [Tencent/rapidjson](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson#usage-at-a-glance):

```cpp
/// nlohmann/json
nlohmann::json json;
ss >> json;
/// Tencent/rapidjson
rapidjson::Document json;
json.parse(ss.str());
```

Comment: В данном случае произойдет копирование всего входящего сообщения в stringstream, что неприемлимо, так как суммарная длина этого сообщения может быть довольно велика. Задача как раз в том, чтобы избежать необходимости полного считывания сообщения и парсить кусками на лету

Comment: @АндрейКурулёв ну а ничего что объект который вы получите в результате будет еще больше чем строка? (если там не будет кучи базовых типов: int, double и т.д.)

Comment: Объект-то ладно, этого не избежать. А вот от предварительного считывания всего сообщения хочется избавиться. Длинна одного сообщения может быть несколько мегабайт, поэтому просто так считывать его целиком в память очень не хочется

Comment: @АндрейКурулёв хорошо, давайте по другому. Вот, у вас есть объект который будет строиться по мере поступления новых данных. Мы знаем что его размер будет больше строкового представления в силу накладных расходов. Вы предлагате не дежать в памяти строку потому что она большая но держать еще БОЛЬШИЙ json объект....

Comment: Этот json-объект мне нужен будет в любом случае и поэтому я не могу отказаться от держания его в памяти, а сама строка, которая занимать будет объем памяти того же порядка, что сам объект, мне абсолютна не нужна

Comment: @АндрейКурулёв https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72897/json---

Comment: Джентльмены, ну давайте подумаем: раз библиотеки для разбора json работают с **потоком**, пусть даже `stringstream` - то можно просто реализовать поток-обертку поверх сокета (если таких нет готовых) и работать... Будет ли библиотека разбора json сначала читать все в память или нет - это уже вопрос второй, но читать все в память самому, и только потом передавать в библиотеку через поток - без этого точно можно обойтись. Есть ли такие готовые потоки - не знаю, как-то начал реализовывать такой вариант для себя - в общем-то, вполне реально, хотя и не довел до конца...

Comment: @Harry вот если бы вы прочитали историю чата, вы бы поняли что вопрос стоял иначе

Comment: @АндрейКурулёв разве я не прав?

Comment: Вопрос был как раз про то, можно ли избавиться от полного чтения в память, проводя разбор входных данных кусками и храня только уже разобранный кусок + состояние парсера